# sql server - library management system design

Tags: database

I'm designing a library database schema, let's say there is a book, it belongs to several subjects, how to design the column to store those subjects? use nvarchar to store the subjectId(s)?

```
---------
Book
---------
id    ----- int 
title ----- nvarchar(50)
subjectId ----- int (foreign key to Subject table)

---------
Subject
---------
id    ----- int 
name ----- nvarchar(50)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO, the proper way to do this is to add another table that contains the relationships.  Here is an article that explains it  http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php

Comment: if i have another table "Video", it also belongs several subjects, if i create one more table "VideoBelong", it seems not quite efficient.

Comment: It only seem that way. Db engines are made for this kinda thing.  Besides the alternatives are way worse

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to create one more table `BookBelong( bookId, subjectId)`
BookId and subjectId have to be keys.

Comment: if i have another table "Video", it also belongs several subjects, if i create one more table "VideoBelong", it seems not quite efficient.